# how to say "They think they have it bad" more formally

Tags: they

i wrote "They think they have it bad," in my essay but my teacher said it was too informal.

Comment: That group of individuals is under the impression that they are being deprived or discriminated against.

Comment: Can you provide context?

Comment: They don't realize that others are worse off than they are.

Answer (score 3):

I take phrases like that apart to make them more illustrative using the good old dictionary or thesaurus.

They: who are they? towns people, my parents. I'm choosing The Students
Think: (tons of options here)
use a synonym for think: assume, assert, are under the impression, I'm choosing determined.
They have it bad. - find another word for bad or better yet be specific.

These students are determined to believe they have more homework than did earlier generations.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be **than** instead then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the context (you might have to change the sentence structure) but you could talk about how **they are self absorbed in their own problems**, meaning they don't consider that other people have their own/bigger problems to deal with.

You might also describe them as **ignorant** (to how good they have it) or **sheltered** (From real life), depending on the context of your essay, which would give you more to talk about - why are they ignorant? who sheltered them and why?